# How to tell if a convergent series of a sequence of functions is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Let's say I have $f_{n}:A=\mathbb{\left[-a,a\right]}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where each $f_{n}$ is continuous on $\left[-a,a\right]$, with $a>0$. Also, I have that $f_{*}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}$ converges uniformly on $A$ (does this matter for what I am asking?). How can I show that $f_{*}$ is differentiable on $B=\left(-a, a\right)$? Do I just need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}^{\prime}$ converges uniformly on $B$? If so, I don't see why this allows us to say that $f_{*}$ is differentiable on $B$, and an explanation would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Does the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) serve as a counter-example?

Comment: @KennyLau, no it does not. If we look at the Weierstrass function $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\pi k^{a}x\right)}{\pi k^{a}}$, where $f_{k}=\frac{\sin\left(\pi k^{a}x\right)}{\pi k^{a}}$, then $f_{k}^{\prime}=\cos\left(\pi k^{a}x\right)$ and on the interval $\left[-1,1\right]$, $f_{k}^{\prime}$ doesn't converge uniformly. I'm not sure how it would serve as a counter-example since I was asking about uniform convergence of the series of derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f_i'$ are continuous, and $f_i'\to g$ uniformly. Then I claim
that $g=f'$ (where $f$ is your $f_*$). Now
$$\int_{-a}^x g(t)\,dt=\lim_{i\to\infty}\int_{-a}^x f_i'(t)\,dt=\lim_{i\to\infty}(f_i(x)-f_i(-a))
=f(x)-f(a)$$
using uniform convergence of the $f_i'$. Now invoke the Fundamental Theorem
of Calculus to get $g=f'$.